# angular google maps window close button drifting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, onsen-ui, angular-google-maps

Our application in using Onsen and angular-google-maps. As shown in the example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vCSV.png), the "x" in the Google Maps InfoWindow is slowly drifting each time the map is reloaded.

All windows on the map open with the "x" in the same, correct, location the first time.  Closing the map page `popPage()` and opening the map `pushPage()` causes the "x" to drift up and to the right 8px.  The following is generated? and placed in the DOM below the content I put in the `<ui-gmap-window>` tags.

```
<div style="width: 19.5px; height: 19.5px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; transform: translateZ(0px); right: 15px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000;">
    <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -3px; top: -504px; width: 88.5px; height: 738px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
</div>
```

Back and reopen:

```
<div style="width: 19.5px; height: 19.5px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; transform: translateZ(0px); right: 7px; top: 4px; z-index: 10000;">
    <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: -3px; top: -504px; width: 88.5px; height: 738px; -webkit-user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
</div>
```

How can I determine what is causing this drift?

**Update** 2015-01-22:

I currently have a workaround.

```
function fixInfoWindow(){
    $timeout(function(){
        $(".gm-style-iw").each(function(){
            if(this.parentNode.style.visibility != "hidden" && this.nextSibling != null){
                this.nextSibling.style.right = "10px";
                this.nextSibling.style.top = "8px";
                this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.right = "3px";
                this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.top = "1px";
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This moves the "x" and the hidden item that closes the window when pressed to the proper location.  I call this function at the end of the functions that set each InfoWindow visible.

My [example](https://github.com/jonman364/maptest) can also be reproduced in Chrome with device emulation turned on.

I still have not found the cause of the drift.

Comment: That's really strange. Is it possible for you to create a small example where this bug is reproduced?

Comment: Example [here](https://github.com/jonman364/maptest). I uploaded as a Cordova app, but the files in www can just be served. It does not drift on a desktop browser, but does in iOS and Android (Cordova or browsers). To recreate: 1. Click Push Page 2. 2. Click the marker (note the close button position). 3. Click Back. 4. Repeat 1 - 3 multiple times.